# Make comment specific to post

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I rendered all of the posts using `v-for`, but now I want to add a comment section to each. I don't know how to make a connection between a comment and a post. As you can see in the code, the comment section renders for all post cards, but how can it be specific to each post? (I am not sure of the logic and how I can implement it).

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="item in userList" :key="item.uid">
    <div class="row q-py-xs">
      <q-card flat class="bg-grey-3 full-width user-card">
        <q-card-section>
          <div class="text-body1 q-ma-xs" id="postDtls">
            {{ item.postDetails }}
          </div>
          <div class="row q-gutter-sm">
            <q-chip square>
              <q-avatar icon="home" color="amber-10" text-color="white" />
              {{ item.postAddress }}
            </q-chip>
          </div>
        </q-card-section>
        <q-card-section> </q-card-section>
        <q-card-section>
          <q-input
            outlined
            id="cmInput"
            v-model="cmOffer"
            class="bg-grey-1"
            color="amber-10"
            label-slot
            clearable
          >
          
            <template v-slot:label>
              <span class="text-weight-bold text-deep-orange">write</span>
              your comment
            </template>
            <template v-slot:append>
              <q-btn
                round
                flat
                icon="move_to_inbox"
                v-on:click="submitComment()"
              />
            </template>
          </q-input>
          <q-btn push dense class="full-width q-my-xs" color="amber-10" label="send message directly" />
        </q-card-section>
      </q-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from "vue";
import { db } from "src/boot/firebase";
import { collection, query, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

export default {
  setup() {
    return {
      userList: ref([]),
      cmList: ref([]),
      idList: ref([]),
      cmOffer: ref("")
    };
  },
  async created() {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "post"));
    const postCm = await getDocs(collection(db, "post"));
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      let docData = doc.data();
      this.userList.unshift(docData);
    });
    postCm.forEach(doc => {
      let cmData = doc.data();
      this.cmList.unshift(cmData);
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create array of comments for every post, and then update them accordingly. Please take look at following snippet:

```js
const { ref } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup () {
    const userList = ref([{uid: 1, postDetails: 'post 1', postAddress: '1', comments: ['comment 1', 'comment 2']}, {uid: 2, postDetails: 'post 2', postAddress: '2', comments: []}])
    const cmOffer = ref([])
    const submitComment = (id, i) => {
      userList.value = userList.value.map(user => {
        if(user.uid === id) {
          user.comments.push(cmOffer.value[i])    
        }
        return {...user}
      })
      cmOffer.value = []
    }
    return { userList, cmOffer, submitComment }
  }
})

app.use(Quasar)
app.mount('#q-app')
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.4.13/dist/quasar.prod.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div id="q-app">
  {{ userList }}
  <div v-for="(item, idx) in userList" :key="item.uid">
    <div class="row q-py-xs">
      <q-card flat class="bg-grey-3 full-width user-card">
        <q-card-section>
          <div class="text-body1 q-ma-xs" id="postDtls">
            {{ item.postDetails }}
          </div>
          <div class="row q-gutter-sm">
            <q-chip square>
              <q-avatar icon="home" color="amber-10" text-color="white" />
              {{ item.postAddress }}
            </q-chip>
          </div>
        </q-card-section>
        <q-card-section> 
          <div class="text-body1 q-ma-xs" v-for="(comment, i) in item.comments" :key="i" >
            {{ comment }}
          </div>
        </q-card-section>
        <q-card-section>
          <q-input outlined id="cmInput" v-model="cmOffer[idx]" class="bg-grey-1" color="amber-10" label-slot clearable>
            <template v-slot:label>
              <span class="text-weight-bold text-deep-orange">write</span>
              your comment
            </template>
            <template v-slot:append>
              <q-btn round flat icon="move_to_inbox" @click="submitComment(item.uid, idx)" />
            </template>
          </q-input>
          <q-btn push dense class="full-width q-my-xs" color="amber-10" label="send message directly" @click="submitComment(item.uid, idx)" />
        </q-card-section>
      </q-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.4.13/dist/quasar.umd.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining your code to me in more detail?

Comment: @Pooya Panahandeh hey mate, so You are using firebase/firestore and have post collection in there. First You can structure your post collection like `userList `  in code. That way You have just one api call and You can easily manipulate comments

Comment: Basically first yoo loop over all posts and inside them you loop again over comments for  every post. ofc snippet is just an example so I removed firebase stuff, you need to handle getting and saving data to firestore.

Comment: thanks a lot for explaining it to me :)